# Android Studio Get Application Directory dataDir

Tags: android

In other Apps I can access files in directories like `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com,xxx,yyy/files`

In my own app I want to use it too. But with `getApplicationInfo().dataDir` I receive `/data/user/0/com.xx.yy/files`

How can I receive the path to `/storage...` and how to create this directory (it was not create automatically after installing the App)

Comment: Call `getExternalFilesDir()` on a suitable `Context`.

Answer (score 1):

Now I find out that `getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()` do the job